# Tomcat Serving another URL

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, jetty

I have about 10 sites running in a single tomcat instance. I have been experiencing this issue for over a month now.

Randomly, tomcat serves a content from other webapps. For example if i am requesting for index.jsp it serves some design png from another web application.

It is hard to reproduce the problem, but i have experienced this very often.

I tried increasing the number of worker thread, did not help. I have a shared tomcatThreadPool between the webapps, dont know if that might be a problem.

Any pointer would be very much appreciated. Please suggest, shall i migrate to Jetty instead.

Thank you

Comment: What Tomcat version? I recall threadsafety issues like that in ancient versions (4.x or 5.0). Latest 6.0 or 7.0 should be stable. Otherwise it's time to post an issue report to the Tomcat guys.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the context.xml and web.xml if you have right specification of context, filter, etc. - problem like that have been shown in version 4.X, so try latest version as BalusC says.